# css navigate through background image

Tags: css

I have a simple html document.

A div inside the body, which contains the following css rules:

```
html,body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}    
#game {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 1000px;
        background-image:url(../img/test.jpg); 
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="game">

<div class="moneybar">
   <div class="moneyscore brown" id="score">0</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to achieve: when on Mobile, if I have a 480px screen, I only see a portion of the background image. And that's fine. But I also want to 'navigate' (drag/scroll) the rest of the background .

Problem: the background does not 'move', 'scroll' ... I don't know which term to use.

I am making a simple game, so if I place a building on the top of the map (which is the full screen background image), I should be able to navigate down and see other buildings. 
I hope I have been clear enough.

Comment: With navigate I assume you mean a drag effect?

Comment: do you mean scroll the image?

Comment: scroll...drag... ye

Comment: You could use `background-attachment: scroll;` property. `scroll` is default value and allows background image to scroll with `div`. But since you set div width and height as 100%, the div just fills the screen , thus it can't to be scrolled. As a possible way - to achieve what you want, you need to set width and height of div to 1000px

Comment: @Banzay even setting width and height of div to 1000px, it does not scroll. (i used background-attachment: scroll; )

Comment: @DregKorig, so it's difficult to say what is reason. put your HTML code to your question

Comment: @Banzay code updated

Comment: I suspected that `#div` isn't true id :)

Comment: ye it's game ...same :D

Comment: I think you need to replace `#div` with `#game` ID in your CSS

Comment: I updated my code, my original code had #game, of course. I just changed it when posted here. The sustance is the same, i have no scroll or drag on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me from your question precisely what result you are looking to achieve. But if I have understood correctly then you simply need to remove:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.game {
width: 1000px;
height: 1000px;
background: radial-gradient(blue, green , yellow, orange, red);
}

.game .scorebar {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 36px;
line-height: 36px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-size: 24px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: rgb(127, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="game">

<div class="scorebar">Score Bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's what I was looking for, except for the scorebar (but I can adjust it by myself). Is it possible to hide scrollbars on mobile? Because hiding overflow does not allow me to scroll / drag.

Comment: It might be possible to hide the mobile vertical scrollbar if you can give `.game` a width which is only slightly wider than the viewport (say `110vw`) and then declare `body {overflow-x: hidden;}`.